# check if 2 dimensional array is completely empty perl

Tags: arrays, perl

My understanding is that I can use

```
if (@array) { print "array not null"; }
```

to test if all the elements of an array are null.  Is there a way I can use this to test a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: `if (@array)` test if array is empty/has no elements. If it has elements and these are undef/null, it will be boolean true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially you need to loop through the first dimension of the array to find out if any of the sub-arrays contain anything. This works:

```
use List::Util qw( any );

if (any { @$_ } @array) { print "array not null\n"; }
```

If you're stuck using an old version of List::Util that doesn't provide `any`, in this case `first` will work as a reasonable substitute:

```
use List::Util qw( first );

if (first { @$_ } @array) { print "array not null\n"; }
```

Though I think than `any` better clarifies the *intent* of the code.

Comment: Why not just use `map @$_, @array`?

Comment: @Zaid `any` and `first` are short circuited. Map will loop even if first element is not empty

Comment: @DVK : (rolls eyes) :)

Comment: @Zaid - if your list has 100000000 elements, it's not such a trivial optimization

Comment: @DVK : Totally agree. To each his/her own problem domain.

Comment: @Zaid: I think you mean `grep @$_, @array`

Comment: In this case I think `grep` and `map` work out to be much of a muchness.

Comment: @DVK, you don't even need a list 100000000 elements long. Even on a list as simple as `([],[],[],[],[0],[],[],[],[])`, `any` and `first` come out ahead of `grep` and `map`.